# Rectifiers operation when there is a sudden voltage drop

Tags: power-electronics, rectifier

Currently studying rectifiers and came along a paragraph in a book that left me puzzled.

"In a full-bridge rectifier supplying an inductive load, if there is a sudden drop on the AC voltage at the input of the rectifier, the firing angle will immediately drop to zero degrees".

I'm very puzzled about this. What is the evidence on that? My suspect is that it has something to do with the current continuity on the inductive load, the current can't simply have a sudden drop. But how does that makes the firing angle go to zero? Why should that happen?

Another question I have is related with the firing circuit of the thyristors, that makes them transition to conduction. Now if there is a breakdown and the gate current/voltage of the thyristors suddenly drops to zero, they will cut off, right? What happens now with the current /voltage on the inductive load? Then again it can't simply just drop to zero, in the case of the current. But where to does the inductive load discharges? To the thyristors? Do I simply create a spark and the circuit is ruined? Maybe with a freewheeling diode in anti-parallel with the load, I could solve the hazard?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Was there a picture alongside the words in your book and was it actually called full-bride?

Comment: Full-bridge! I'll put the picture in a few seconds

Answer (score 0):

> What happens now with the current /voltage on the inductive load? Then
>   again it can't simply just drop to zero, in the case of the current.
>   But where to does the inductive load discharges?

It discharges into a voltage source, the inductive load becomes a generator for that amount of time. Thyristor conducts the current as before (until the current drops to zero), there is no current break only the voltage is now reversed, therefore the power becomes negative - it is flowing back to the source.

> In a full-bridge rectifier supplying an inductive load, if there is a
>   sudden drop on the AC voltage at the input of the rectifier, the
>   firing angle will immediately drop to zero degrees

Usually is the control circuit which defines the firing angle and not the thyristor by itself.

> Now if there is a breakdown and the gate current/voltage of the
>   thyristors suddenly drops to zero, they will cut off, right?

No, because thyristors are ignited with a pulse, and they stop conducting by themselves (they are latching) when the current through drops to a minimum holding current.